# how to pass dynamically inserted data from java script to php using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 
var httpBuildQuery = function(params) {

    if (typeof params === 'undefined' || typeof params !== 'object') {
        params = {};
        return params;
    }

    var query = '?';
    //var index = '';
    var index = <?php echo json_encode($array3); ?>;

    
      for (var i in index) {
        //index++;
        //var param = index[i];
        var value = params[i];
        if (index == 1) {
            query += value + '=' +  value +'.value';
        } 
        else {

            query += '&' + value + '=' +  value +'.value';
        }

    }
    return query;
};


var build = document.getElementById('submit');
var output = document.getElementById('output');

build.onclick = function() {
 
 var parameters = <?php echo json_encode($array2); ?>;
    
  var $query = httpBuildQuery(parameters);
    //output.firstChild.nodeValue = $query;
    alert($query);
   var $z=document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = $query;
 
   
   //var $my_variable = "something";
$("#build").click(function() {
   
$.ajax({
     url: 'insert_value.php',
     data: {x: $query},
     type: 'POST'

});
});

};
</script>
```

```html
   

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

here I'm uploaded my code here i'm generating controls dynamically and trying to insert those controls values into some table so I have to pass the values from javascript to php

in javascript i'm creating query string but it is like ?gender=gender.value&name=name.value so instead of printing like it should take directly values like ?gender=Male&name=sai like this

so plaease anyone help me to solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to go into much complexity, just keep it simple.

code in your php file where you are adding controls dynamically

```
    <form id="myForm">

    // Generate your dynamic content here

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#myForm").submit(function(evt){
  evt.preventDefault();

  var formData = $("#myForm").serialize();
  $.ajax({
        url: "insert_data.php",
        data: formData,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            // do something with the result
        }
 });
});
</script>
```

In Your insert_data.php file you can view this data using `print_r($_POST);`

You can also use https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/ and more about serialize https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: i'm not getting after seeing that because there they have passed directly values here in my case user is providing so can you explain in details according my code

Comment: if you could specify sample data of $array2 and $array3, that will help much to answer easily.

Comment: you must need to include jQuery.js to execute above code. Have you included jQuery..?

Comment: yes.. if you could mention data of $array2 and $array3, purpose of html code and why you don't want to use forms.. it would be much helpful :)

Comment: Zameer I have edited my above code I dont know how to do and I have tried my level best I'm still learner so

Comment: i don't understand what you want to do.. do you want to send a form data to another page using ajax (though you are generating html controls dynamically)..?

Comment: I'm generating controls dynamically by those controls values has to insert into table In arrary2 fetched the name of  controls like gender name and in array3 in which column it should insert those are column number of db table and My db table will be like this col1,col2,col3,col4 so on

Comment: answer is updated.. Instead of passing data through two different array use **Associative Array in PHP** this will generate array like ['name of control'=>'col_name_in_db',['name of control'=>'col_name_in_db'... ]

Comment: thanq Zameer some how your links has made something good tq:);